# Wordpress acf trying to hide and show divs in a list, using acf repeater field

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi im basically creating a help page, where there is a dynamic list created using the repeater field.

Each list item there is a line of text, that when clicked on should show some more content (and hide it when clicked on again).

Now i can get it to work for the first item in the list… but every new item only shows/hides the first item.

Im assuming i need to do some for each for the id or something i just don't know how to.

Thx for any help, here is the code:

```
<?php if (have_rows('video_felt')): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while (have_rows ('video_felt')): the_row();
            //vars
            $afsnitOverskrift = get_sub_field('afsnit_titel');
            ?>
                <li>
                    <?php if($afsnitOverskrift): ?>
                         <?php echo $afsnitOverskrift; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>

                </li>
                    <?php if (have_rows('video_liste')): ?>    
                        <ul>
                            <?php while (have_rows ('video_liste')): the_row();
                            //vars
                            $videListe = get_sub_field('video_navn');
                            $videoLinker = get_sub_field('vide_link');?>
                            <li onclick="myFunction()">
                                <?php if($videListe): ?>
                                    <a  ><?php echo $videListe; ?></a> 
                                    <div id="myDIV" style="display:none;">
                                        <div class="youtube-player" data-id="<?php echo $videoLinker;?>"></div>

                                    </div>   
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </li>
                            <?php endwhile;?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif;?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif;?>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edit your code with jquery kindly check below working code.

```
<?php if (have_rows('video_felt')): ?>
    <ul class="videoul">
        <?php while (have_rows ('video_felt')): the_row();
        //vars
        $afsnitOverskrift = get_sub_field('afsnit_titel');
        ?>
            <li>
                <?php if($afsnitOverskrift): ?>
                     <?php echo $afsnitOverskrift; ?>
                <?php endif;?>

            </li>
                <?php if (have_rows('video_liste')): ?>    
                    <ul>
                        <?php while (have_rows ('video_liste')): the_row();
                        //vars
                        $videListe = get_sub_field('video_navn');
                        $videoLinker = get_sub_field('vide_link');?>
                        <li >
                            <?php if($videListe): ?>
                                <a  ><?php echo $videListe; ?></a> 
                                <div class="myDIV" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="youtube-player" data-id="<?php echo $videoLinker;?>"></div>

                                </div>   
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endwhile;?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif;?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
```

**jQuery**

```
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('body').on('click', 'ul.videoul li', function() {
           jQuery("div.myDIV").hide();
           jQuery(this).find("div.myDIV").toggle();

        });
      });
   </script>
```